# How can I run Steam?

Tags: steam

I'm a new user of Ubuntu, and of course I'm a gamer. Now, my problem is simple, I cant install Steam. I downloaded steam in App Manager and tried to open it, but nothing happened. The app icon appeared in the tray and after a few seconds it went away. The system is fully upgraded. What can I do?

Comment: Try opening a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and running `steam`. [Edit] your question and show us any error messages that appear.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Steam via synaptic and download from the official webpage:

http://store.steampowered.com/about/